# Code compliance for outdoor 20 amp receptacle?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

Looking to add a 20 amp receptacle on the outside of my house, on a separate circuit. I don't know what NEC codes to look out for. It will be on the outside wall of the house, if that helps. The code I *am* familiar with is using the correct gauge for a 20 amp circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an outdoor 20 ampere circuit, you'll need a

- 20 ampere breaker, obviously.
- Minimum 12 AWG conductors.
- GFCI protection either via a breaker, standalone device, or receptacle.
- Weather-resistant type receptacle.
- A weatherproof in-use receptacle cover (identified as "*extra-duty*").

If the box is not *in* the wall, you'll also need

- A weatherproof enclosure.
- Wet location rated protection of the wires via conduit, rated cable sheath, or other approved raceway.

Comment: Does LFMC count as Wet location rated protection, the house is brick so the box won't be in a wall.

Comment: Liquidtight Flexible Metal Conduit (Type LFMC) can be used in a wet location. However, it cannot be used where subject to physical damage. If it would be in danger from a weed whacker, you might not want to use it. It shouldn't be a problem, but you'll also want to make sure it's not exposed to temperatures in excess of the rating (*-30°C (-22°F) - 80°C (176°F)*).

Comment: so, are we talking sch 80 PVC then? weed wacker damage is possible, though unlikely lol.

Comment: If you have LFMC laying around, I'd check with the local building department to see what they think.  I can't see where you're installing it, so I can't say for sure from here.